# well formed json parsed using php

Tags: php, json

I am storing data in `json` format which will be parsed by php.
The values for each object (car, bicycle, motorcycle) are colors while the string is just the title `color`.
This does not seem to be working well when parsing in `php` because `"color"` is repeating.

What is the best way to format a list such as this?

```
{
    "car": {
            "color":"blue",
            "color":"green",
            "color":"red"
    },
    "bicycle": {
            "color":"purple",
            "color":"white",
            "color":"black"
    },
    "motorcycle": {
            "color":"orange",
            "color":"red",
            "color":"green"
    }
}
```

when parsing

```
$jsonArr = json_decode($json,true);

foreach ($jsonArr as $key => $value){
     echo $key, ' : ';
     foreach($value as $v){
             echo $v."  ";
     }
}
```

this returns only the last item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be valid JSON but even `JSON.parse` only keeps the last value for the repeated key.

I'd go with this sort of structure

```
"car": {
    "colors": ["blue", "green", "red"]
}
```

Comment: thank you,  would the same logic and rule apply to javascript?

Comment: @tq yes (see `JSON.parse` in my answer)